# Is there an example how to use a callback in flyway?

Tags: callback, flyway

Is there an example how to use a callback in flyway 3.2 that works using maven? The afterMigrate method supplies a SQL connection object but it is closed?

My desire is to use this to create stored procedures from a collection of files in source control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL-based callbacks by simply creating a sql file with the name of the callback: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks.html

Comment: That would be great if I could specify a directory and it would execute all the files in it. These are plsql packages and maintaining them as a single file would make development much harder

Comment: For views, procedures, functions,packages, ... there is now a feature called "repeatable migrations". See: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#repeatable-migrations. Repeatable migrations have a checksum. They are executed every time their checksum changes.